# Why do the buttons open the same component instead of opening each button each component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have one parent component with 3 buttons and 3 children components. Each button should open one component but with my code the 3 buttons open the same component when I click on the buttons.
The children components are in 3 different files and the parent component has one state. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code.
I pasted one child component example but they're 3 alerts.
Besides, my task for school specifies this: The state should have three values representing info, success and failed. How can I do it?

parent component

```
export const Messages = () => {

  const [showInfo, setShowInfo] = useState(false);
  

  return (
    <Stack>
       <Button
        onClick={() => setShowInfo(true)}
      >
        open info message
      </Button>
      <InfoMessage open={showInfo} onClose={()=> setShowInfo(false)} />
      <Button
        onClick={() =>  setShowInfo(true)}
      >
        open success message
      </Button>
      <SuccessMessage open={showInfo} onClose={()=>  setShowInfo(false)} />
      <Button
        onClick={()=>  setShowInfo(true)}
      >
        open error message
      </Button>
      <ErrorMessage open={showInfo} onClose={() =>  setShowInfo(false)} />
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

Child component (one example)

```
interface InfoMessageProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}

export const InfoMessage = ({ open, onClose }: InfoMessageProps) => {

  const handleClose = (): void => {
    onClose();
  };

 
  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={4000}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      onClick={handleClose}
      // TransitionComponent={transition}
    >
      <Alert
        sx={{
              width: '487px',
              height: '104px',
              paddingTop: '20px',
              paddingLeft: '20px',
              backgroundColor: '#FDFDFD',
        }}
        icon={false}
        action={(
          <IconButton
            aria-label="close"
            color="inherit"
            size="small"
            onClick={handleClose}
          >
            <CloseIcon fontSize="inherit" />
          </IconButton>
        )}
      >
        <AlertTitle sx={{ paddingRight:'80px' }}>
          <Typography variant='headings.h4'>title</Typography>
        </AlertTitle>
        <Typography variant='captions.default'>Insert message here</Typography>
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be your solution

```
export const Messages = () => {

  const [msgStatus, setMsgStatus] = useState("");      

  return (
    <Stack>
       <Button
        onClick={() => setMsgStatus("info")}
      >
        open info message
      </Button>
      <InfoMessage open={msgStatus === "info"} onClose={()=> setMsgStatus("")} />
      <Button
        onClick={() =>  setMsgStatus("success")}
      >
        open success message
      </Button>
      <SuccessMessage open={msgStatus === "success"} onClose={()=>  setMsgStatus("")} />
      <Button
        onClick={()=>  setMsgStatus("error")}
      >
        open error message
      </Button>
      <ErrorMessage open={msgStatus === "error"} onClose={() =>  setMsgStatus("")} />
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you should use different states for each component. What's happening is because showInfo is true, every component is being rendered and overlapping with each other.

EDIT:

You can change your onClick function and have a condition to render each component:

```
export const Messages = () => {

  const [showInfo, setShowInfo] = useState(false);
  const [conditionalState,setConditionState] =useState(false);
  
  const setShow = (value) => {
    setShowInfo(true);
    setConditionState(value);
  }

  return (
    <Stack>
       <Button
        onClick={() => {setShow(0)}
      >
        open info message
      </Button>
      {conditionalState === 0 && 
        <InfoMessage open={showInfo} onClose={()=> setShowInfo(false)} />
      }
      <Button
        onClick={() => {setShow(1)}
      >
        open success message
      </Button>
      {conditionalState === 1 && 
        <SuccessMessage open={showInfo} onClose={()=>  setShowInfo(false)} />
      }
      <Button
        onClick={() => {setShow(2)}
      >
        open error message
      </Button>
      {conditionalState === 2 && 
        <ErrorMessage open={showInfo} onClose={() =>  setShowInfo(false)} />
      }
      
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks, but my task for school specifies this: The state should have three values representing info, success and failed. How can I do it?

Comment: You can change your onClick function and have a condition to render each component.

Comment: I'm new to this, Could you provide me with an example in my code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: cool, thanks for the explanation in the code. How can I have only one state with the 3 different values representing info, success and failed. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Ok. Got your question now. let me modify my answer.

Comment: Try my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

A minor correction is needed in your code.
You should have different states for different alerts in your `parent.js` like this :

```
export const Messages = () => {

  const [showStatus, setShowStatus] = useState("");
  

  return (
    <Stack>
       <Button
        onClick={() => setShowStatus("info")}
      >
        open info message
      </Button>
      <InfoMessage open={showStatus=="info"} onClose={()=> setShowStatus("")} />
      <Button
        onClick={() =>  setShowStatus("success")}
      >
        open success message
      </Button>
      <SuccessMessage open={showStatus == "success"} onClose={()=>  setShowStatus("")} />
      <Button
        onClick={()=>  setShowStatus("error")}
      >
        open error message
      </Button>
      <ErrorMessage open={showStatus=="error"} onClose={() =>  setShowStatus("")} />
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

Comment: According to requirements, I suppose there should be only one `useState`, but the object would be initialized with `{ info: false, success: false, error: false }` and use these subvalues. This will give it a state with three values and 3 states with one value each.

Comment: thanks, Is it possible to give the useState example? const [showInfo, setShowInfo] = useState(here I paste the object?);